# I can't add a server to Minecraft Pocket Edition v0.8.0

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Why can't I add an online server to my minecraft pocket edition v0.8.0?

I've tried uninstalling it then downloading it again but it doesn't work. Is there something that I must do for it to let me add a server?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It won't let me delete the example IP adress

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the bug in android where you can't delete the existing text, then you need to download another keyboard. The default keyboard has a bug in it and Google is working on fixing the problem. Use another keyboard, like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard).

Answer (score 0):

Heard you have problems with the servers right? Well, here is the answer! Go to play, Then click on edit! After that you clock on external! Now you can call the server whatever you want, and the IP address you need to find out! Don't change the ip port! Or else it won't work! I really hope this worked / helped. Tell me if there is something wrong! :-)